# OWIN OAuth server sample code example

Tags: oauth-2.0, owin, katana

I am using the sample code from this OWIN project http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server  and I didnt the deploy of the solutions .When I try to get a authorization token from the server I get redirected to the login page and then to the authorize page but when I am clicking on grant the page is not rediretcing me ..Checking the code it is this am I supposed to create the redirect login with access token myself or is there some configuration I am missing here .

If anyone familiar with the project can please let me know.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form.Get("submit.Grant")))
                {
                    identity = new ClaimsIdentity(identity.Claims, "Bearer", identity.NameClaimType, identity.RoleClaimType);
                    foreach (var scope in scopes)
                    {
                        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:oauth:scope", scope));
                    }
                    authentication.SignIn(identity);
```